# Error returning a mapped Business Object to an EF Entity partial class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to map a business object to a Data-First, auto-generated Entity. However, the Iam getting an error in my mapper class where I am returning a `new Lab`.

The error is `"Cannot Convert expression type 'LabManager.DataAcces.Lab' to return type LabManager.BusinessObjects.BusinessObjects.Lab"`

My question is: Why am I getting this error when I am returning exactly what it expects in my mapper class?

My business object looks like this:

```
namespace LabManager.BusinessObjects.BusinessObjects
{
    public class Lab
    {
        public Lab()
        {

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Cylinder> Cylinders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Entity I am mapping the business object to is:

```
public partial class Lab
{
    public Lab()
    {
        this.Cylinders = new HashSet<Cylinder>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cylinder> Cylinders { get; set; }
}
```

And I am just using a hand-rolled mapper class (no AutoMapper):

```
namespace EmitLabManager.DataAccess.ModelMapper
public class Mapper
{
   internal static BusinessObjects.BusinessObjects.Lab GetLabs(Lab entity)
   {
        return new Lab
        {
             Id = entity.Id,
             Name = entity.Name,
             Cylinders = entity.Cylinders
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use full type name for Lab only in method declaration and not everywhere?

Comment: @Kniganapolke That's a good question. I suppose I should. I've never really had to qualify like this before. I usually try to keep my object names rather unique so has not to have to qualify in this manner. I am most likely going to refactor the names and redundant namespace as well (BusinessObjects.BusinessObjects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a namespace conflict.  You'll want to fully-qualify the constructor in your GetLabs function:

```
return new BusinessObjects.BusinessObjects.Lab
    {
         Id = entity.Id,
         Name = entity.Name,
         Cylinders = entity.Cylinders
    };
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding that namespace to the initializer did clear up "the red" on ID and Name, but I continue to have an error on the line where I am initializing Cylinders. The error now is `"Cannot convert source type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<LabManager.DataAccess.Cylinder>' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<LabManager.BusinessObjects.BusinessObjects.Cylinder>'` Is this still a namespace issue?

Comment: Fully qualify type of the argument as well.

Comment: Yes, that's the same issue.  However, you'll need to write a conversion method for the entity.Cylinders class - the name is the same as the Cylinders property in your Lab object, but they're actually different objects entirely.  The EF might have created a converter for you; otherwise, you'll have to make a new BusinessObjects.Cylinder and assign the properties one by one from the DataAccess.Cylinder.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of a conversion method? I checked and the The Cylinder class in DataAccess is singular and in the DataAccess.Lab class the property name is plural. Shouldnt this be distinct enough?

Comment: @StevenWestbrook OHHHHHH I just saw what you meant about the Cylinders being the same but different. I read the error again.

Comment: No, the type names aren't really relevant (except that they're muddying the issue of course).  The problem is that you have two types.  They're both called "Cylinder," but the compiler doesn't know they're supposed to be the same.  So here's an example conversion method to convert type X, with property Z, to type Y:
Y convert(X input)
{
Y output = new Y();
output.Z = input.Z;
return output;
}

Note that there should really be a way in EF to do this - probably a constructor for the Cylinder business object that takes a DataAccess Cylinder or something like that.